# .NET Class property as object, such as System.String

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if this is possible, or even how to properly word this.

I am creating a new webAPI that I want to use with an offline app. The app connects to the api (before going offline) and pulls down a list of fields to generate a dynamic form. I want to supply a list of fields to the client. In simple terms this might be `id` and `description`.

However, to generate the form exactly as I want it, I might want to supply a field "type" such as `System.DateTime` or `System.String`. Is it possible to do this?

In pseudocode this might be:

```
public class EntityType
{
    public Guid EntityTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Object Type { get; set; }
}
```

I might then want to create an `EntityType` like this:

```
EntityType entityType = new EntityType { 
    EntityTypeId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Description = "Visit Date",
    Type = System.DateTime
};
```

It's the `Type = System.DateTime` I want to be able to achieve. I can then have my form generate a field where the type is date. The same might apply for strings for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To represent a *type*, use `Type`:

```
 public Type Type { get; set; }
```

...

```
Type = typeof(DateTime)
```

However! It is unlikely that this will work with webapi, since `Type` is not interchangeable between platforms.

Another option is an `enum` of your expected types; you might find that `TypeCode` has everything you want, but you could also simply create your own `enum` of known types.

Comment: If that doesn't work with webapi, could you "cheat" with generics like this? `public class EntityType<T> { public Type Type { get { return typeof(T); } } }` Or would that have the same problems?